# How to get a value from View to JavaScript in asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-server

I wrote a web application which starts with a view with a area- menu and an area-content. when I click on a menu Item the funktion loads the correct view into
the content-area via js.
How can I get a string from the server to js.

```
$('#area-content').load('@Model.OpeningPage');
```

doesn´t work.

Comment: Does @Model.OpeningPage even work as a url?

Comment: what is value in the @Model.OpeningPage ?

Comment: @Model.OpeningPage is a string

Comment: you can access values using   @Model.Property, is your script in view itself or in a different script file? if so ,.. move it to view using script tag

Comment: the script is in a diffrent script file but linked in the view

Comment: If you want to leave it in an external script you will need to call the method from the view, passing the value to the method from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ajax requests for comunication between js and server.